# Python lists.. Two functions... I have the first(i think) but not the second

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def f(x):
    L1=[]
    for y in range(x):
        L2=[]
        for z in range(x):
            m=randrange(0,100)
            L2.append(m)
        L1.append(L2)
    return(L1)

print(f(5))
```

a function that takes as an input parameter a number x.  It then generates a list of x lists, all x elements long of random numbers and returns it. another function that prints out the second value of the lists generated from the first. Im not quite sure how to write the second function.

Comment: Why not post an attempted solution for the second part? I don't expect too many to solve your homework for you

Answer (score 0):

```
def first(x):
  return [[random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(x)] for _ in range(x)]

def second(L):
  for item in map(operator.itemgetter(1), L):
    print(item)
```

Comment: Can you explain the answer please.

Comment: `map(f, L)` calls the function `f` on each element of the list `L`, and returns a list containing the results of calling `f` on each of these elements. `operator.itemgetter(1)` results in a function that, when called on a list, returns the element at index `1` in that list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that you only want to print the second value of each list, then this:

```
def print_second(L):
    for c in range(len(L)): #go through all of the lists
        if len(L[c]) >= 2:  #don't look for 2nd item of list of length 1
            print(L[c][1])  #print the second item (starting from 0, index 1)
```